# Bash Eval invalid command

Tags: java, bash, eval

I have the following scenario in a .sh file

```
hello="java -cp \"/home/user/libs/*\" org.user.class parameter"
echo "$hello"
eval $($hello)
```

If I try to run the .sh file I get the following exception Error: Could not find or load main class, but if I execute what is printed the application starts.

Is there any escaping that can be done to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that parenthesis for eval expression must be removed.

The correct syntax is:

```
hello="java -cp \"/home/user/libs/*\" org.user.class parameter"
echo "$hello"
eval $hello
```

Answer (score 1):

First, read: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

If you really must do this, don't use a *variable*.  Use an *array*.  Try:

```
hello=(java -cp "/home/user/libs/*" org.user.class parameter)
"${hello[@]}"
```

Comment: The problem is that the command is read from a file and composed on spot using parameters.